# Kafka Streams – best way to get KTable and KStream on same topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have an issue with Kafka Streams (0.10.1.1). I'm trying to create a `KStream`and a `KTable`on the same topic.

The first approach I tried was simple calling the `KStreamBuilder` methods for stream and table on the same topic. This resulted in

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyBuilderException: Invalid topology building: Topic <topicName> has already been registered by another source.
```

OK, this seems to be some restriction built-into Kafka Streams.

My second approach was initially creating a `KTable`and using the `toStream()` method on it. This has the issue that `KTables`do some internal buffering/flushing, so the output stream does not reflect all input elements if a key is occurring multiple times as in my example. This is a problem as I'm counting the occurrences of a key.

The approach that seems to work is to initially create a `KStream`, group it by key and then "reduce" it by discarding the old aggregate and just keeping the new value. I'm not too happy with this approach as a) it seems very complicated and b) the `Reducer` interface does not specify which one is the already aggregated value and which one is the new one. I went with convention and kept the second one, but ... meh.

So the question boils down to: is there a better way? Am I missing something blindingly obvious?

Please keep in mind that I'm not working on a proper use case – this is just me getting to know the Streams-API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

About adding a topic twice: that's not possible, because a Kafka Streams application is a single "consumer group" and thus can only commit offsets for a topic a single time, while adding a topic twice would indicate that the topic get's consumer twice (and independent progress).

For the approach `KTable#toStream()`, you can disable caching via `StreamsConfig` parameter `cache.max.bytes.buffering == 0`. However, this is a global setting and disables caching/deduplication for all `KTable`s (cf. http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#memory-management).

> **Update:** Since Kafka 0.11 it's possible to disable caching for each KTable individually via `Materialized` parameter.

The `groupBy` approach works also, even if it requires some boilerplate. We considering adding `KStream#toTable()` to the API to simplify this transformation. And yes, second argument in `reduce` is the new value -- as reduce is for combining two values, the API has no concept of "old" and "new" and thus the parameters do not have such naming.

Comment: why it is not possible to re-use previously added topic?

Comment: As describe in the answer. Because we use a single consumer and a consumer can subscribe to a topic only once.